# Prove a function is subharmonic?__Gilbarg Exercise

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-analysis, harmonic-functions

[image]

**My attempt:**

By a long time google search I found in a book about how to prove it in the case of harmonic function. Just construct another function $v$ which is harmonic in the $\Omega$, then prove $u=v$.